# How can Celery be made to log each task

Tags: logging, celery

I can log a message from within Celery task with [`get_task_logger`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/internals/reference/celery.utils.log.html#celery.utils.log.get_task_logger). However, I would  like Celery to log a message each time a task runs without me having to log explicitly. Like an access log on a web server.